# Writing a function `objectToMap`

Tags: flowtype

How would one go about writing a function from an object to a Map:

```js
function objectToMap<K, V>(transformKey: string => K, obj: {[key: string]: V}): Map<K, V> {
  const map = new Map()

  const entries = Object.entries(obj)

  for (const [k, v] of entries) {
    map.set(transformKey(k), v)
  }

  return map
}
```

The problem seems to be that the return type of `Object.entries` is `Array<[string, mixed]>`. (See the error below).

```
Cannot return map because mixed [1] is incompatible with V [2] in type argument V [2].

     <somePath>/index.js
     145|     map.set(transformKey(k), v)
     146|   }
     147|
     148|   return map
     149| }
     150|
     151| function makeProficiencyWithProgress(

     /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_149a8c8/core.js
 [1]  54|     static entries(object: $NotNullOrVoid): Array<[string, mixed]>;
```